# Copy a file from temp folder to a browsed location

Tags: .net, vb.net, file-copying

I want to copy a zip file from temp folder to a browsed location (say `Destinydirectory`).

This is my code however it gives me an error:

```
If System.IO.Directory.Exists(My.Computer.FileSystem.CombinePath(My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.Temp, "IXP001.TMP")) Then
    System.IO.Directory.Delete(My.Computer.FileSystem.CombinePath(My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.Temp, "IXP000.TMP"), True)
    FileCopy = "c:\\Users\\Test\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\IXP001.TMP\\bin.zip"
Else
    FileCopy = "c:\\Users\\Test\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\IXP000.TMP\\bin.zip"
End If
File.Copy(FileCopy, Destinydirectory)
```

Comment: If you could give some details about what you tried we might be able to help you better. Did you see: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: IfSystem.IO.Directory.Exists(My.Computer.FileSystem.CombinePath(My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.Temp, "IXP001.TMP")) Then
            System.IO.Directory.Delete(My.Computer.FileSystem.CombinePath(My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.Temp, "IXP000.TMP"), True)
            FileCopy = "c:\\Users\\Test\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\IXP001.TMP\\bin.zip"
        Else
            FileCopy = "c:\\Users\\Test\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\IXP000.TMP\\bin.zip"
        End IfFile.Copy(FileCopy, Destinydirectory)      @Martin Brown

Comment: Is it throwing an exception? If so can you let us have the exact wording of the error message please? Also what is Destinydirectory set to?

Comment: [File.Copy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c6cfw35a(v=vs.110).aspx) requires a filename on both arguments. What is the value of `Destinydirectory`?

Answer (score 0):

This is the code:

System.IO.File.Copy(@"c:\temp\file.zip", @"c:\destination\file.zip");

Which kind of exception you receive?

[Msdn documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.io.file.copy(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: something like" Destinydirectory is a directory not a file".   P.S i can only browse a path or directory for copying .

Comment: the error is that you try to copy a file in a directory that does not exist